# Possible to put Exception Try/Catch Error Messages to Textbox on first page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Usually error messages are thrown to a new webpage when I get some sort of `SocketException`, `WebException`, etc.

Instead of being redirected to a new page with the error messages, is it possible to get the error to show in a textbox on the first page?

Comment: Add the code where the exceptions occur and the html code you have.

Comment: What is your codezzz??

Comment: This makes little sense.  The odds that the page actually makes it to the user's browser are slim.  The odds that she'll debug your software or wants to edit the exception message are zero.

Comment: Define "the first page" and "a new webpage".  If the error happens in response to a request, then the first page is gone at that point.  What gets rendered to the client in response to that request, however, is entirely up to you.

Comment: Yeah right, Its actualy a response to a request. So correct David. Its gone. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous and vague, but usually when you want to handle the exceptions, you can put your code with a [try catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement.

For example;

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("This is a dirty exception");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do something with the exception thrown
    // read the exception message: ex.Message
    // read the exception innerException: ex.InnerException
    // in your case, you can assign the message to a textbox
    this.TextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
}
```